# Azure function HTTP trigger stop eventhandler

Tags: azure-functions

On an AzureFunction, as and when Http message is received I am doing a POST to an external server(3rd party server) through the Function code.

To maintain one connection for ALL the devices, I have hosted the Azure Function on a Server rather than Consumption plan and also creating static httpClient to POST to the external server.

When the Azure Function APP is stopped, I need an eventhandler to unsubscribe from the external server. But I am unable to find a STOP eventhandler for Azure Function. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? The `httpClient` probably just calls a REST service right? So it will automatically be disposed of when the app hosting the function is recycled.

Comment: While disposing, need to add custom code.  OR while doing STOP FunctionApp through the AZURE portal, need a eventhandler to add custom code

Comment: But _why_ do you need to run custom code? Is your 3rd party service statefull?

Comment: need to close the connection established with 3rd party server

Answer (score 1):

There is no OnStop event or something like that you can use to run custom code when your Function stops since Azure Functions hide the app lifecycle.

You could hook into the AppDomain. Try something like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (sender, eventArgs) => 
{
    // Your custom code
};
```